# Sendgrid resulting in an error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: python, sendgrid

My code runs scripts that sends email every 1 hour.
The script was running fine, until the Sendgrid resulted in error HTTP 401 Unauthorized.
I checked up online and found that this could be due to wrong API key or not properly importing the API in the python code. But my code ran fine, up till now.

```
sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
def send_mail(to_email, subject, message, from_email=To("fromemail@id")):
    """
    Input : to_email_list , subject , message string , from_email
    Action: sends mail to all the recipients mentioned in the to_ids list

    """

    try:

        content = Content("text/html", message)
        mail = Mail(from_email, to_email, subject, content)
        mail_json = mail.get()
        print("MAIL JSON", mail_json)

        response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail_json)
        print(response.headers)
        print("response code :", response.status_code)
        print(
            content,
        )

        return True

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False



send_mail_utils.send_mail('toemail','testing','This is the message')
```

I have tried the following :

1. Directly passing the api token id in the  `sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(API)`
2. Using new API TOKEN

Comment: Where are you running this code - on a hosted service or your local machine? I'd recommend to try running it from another device or maybe directly from a REPL to test the API keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this isn't a SendGrid API problem. This may happen because you are not importing the `SENDGRID_API_KEY` properly.

For test only, try using a key hardcoded, p.e. `SENDGRID_API_KEY="xpto123`, instead of the method `os.environ.get()`.